# Reconstruction of a windowed signal (specifically Hamming windowed)

Tags: window-functions

Wondering about the resconstruction of the input signal when an overlapped windowing function has been applied.

I'm specifically applying a Hamming window with 50% overlap and I wish to reconstruct the input signal.

Here http://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/105321-1.php it's given that summing the 50% overlapped windows gives a sum of 1.08.

In order to reconstruct the input signal (with the same exact amplitudes), then can I merely subtract the extra ~".08" from all the samples? Or, equivalently, divide by 1.08?

The overlapp-add does not result into the exact same signal though, but there's some miniscule variation for some reason. By testing with an array of 1.0s I get back varying values that are of the form 0.999 ...

I guess reconstructing doesn't always lead to the same exact input signal, depending on the windowing function and the amount of overlap?

Comment: What is the percentage difference from 1.0?  Any FFT processing will introduce a tiny amount of rounding error or numerical noise, likely well below the S/N of any physical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you ask this at *comp.dsp*?  appears so.  if you do what hotpaw says, your Hamming window will be

$$ w(t) =
\begin{cases}
0.426 \cdot \cos(\pi t) + 0.5 & \text{if }|t| < 1 \\
0.037 & \text{if }|t| = 1 \\
0 & \text{if }|t| > 1
\end{cases} $$

still a Hamming window, but it overlap-adds to 1 (with 50% overlap), rather than 1.08.

Answer (score 0):

If your process has a gain of 1.08, then you will need to divide the processes result by 1.08, not subtract a constant.

Finite numerical processes involving transcendental functions should not be expected to produce exact results in the general case.  Common fast computer processor arithmetic is "only" accurate to about a dozen significant digits.